# localhost/phpmyadmin/ open as https and not as http

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I am trying to open phpmyadmin page in xampp..but i am stuck at one place..when i am trying to  open the page as

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

it give me following error:

[image]

but when i am opening same as

```
https://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

it open successfully..i have check the config.inc.php file it has following setting..

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']            = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']                 = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']             = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']      = true;
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem..i have tried almost everything and continue to do..its been two days..

thanks in advance..

Comment: did you try with different browser?

Comment: @RelicSet No man i haven't tried..it worked in IExplorer :) ..it was not working with Chrome..i should have thought about it..any way thanks buddy..but i am still unaware why it didn't work with chrome..

Comment: Hi @SurajG...can you check mysql services is start or not? if not means You can restart mysql through xampp control ?

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU buddy i have restart and checked but same problem on Chrome..but work fine on IExplorer..but doubt still remains..why not on chrome ???..thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can take look on below 2 document link to solve your issue

just go throw this link you can sure solve your issue

http://www.michaelbarton.name/2009/12/13/forcing-ssl-with-phpmyadmin/

```
// place this at the bottom somewhere
$cfg['ForceSSL'] = false;
```

And also please check below

http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html

Comment: sorry it didn't work for me..i got the solution though confuse why it worked in IExplorer and not chrome..but thanks..

Answer (score 0):

check your `config.inc.php` file

should contain like this by default:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Answer (score -1):

The https makes it more secure than http anyway, so you are best to just use that as it is working